# Google app script: getting data from spreadsheets without having viewing rights (not installable trigger)

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script

The problem is that I have various spreadsheets (a) for which only one person has viewing and editing permissions, still other persons need some data from those spreadsheets (a) for their spreadsheets (b), they also need to be able to get an updated version of the data from the spreadsheets (a)

I created now a workaround using installable triggers with an on edit function (they have to change a specific field in the spreadsheet) to update the data, but the persons want to have a button/drawing which they can click or a menu entry  to get the updated data from the spreadsheets (a).

From my perspective to combine an installable trigger with a button/drawing/menu entry is a dead end. Therefore my question is, if there is any other possibility to grant access to data from spreadsheets without giving viewing or editing rights to the documents where the data comes from...

Would be great if anybody would have an idea, thanks in advance

Comment: To clearify the question a little bit (as I believe there is no way to trigger an installable trigger from a button/menuentry): Is there any other possibility (apart from the installable trigger) to get data from another spreadsheet for which the person doesn't have editing or viewing permission?

Answer (score 1):

There are some limits on the Triggers that are used in a spreadsheet that you are going to run into.  Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) for details.  Essentially, and `onEdit` trigger cannot access/modify another spreadsheet as `They cannot access any services that require authentication as that user.`

To update another spreadsheet outside of the current spreadsheet, I've simply installed a function and a menu item to trigger it. (Is this the dead end you speak of?)  It does depend on the user to update the group, but that has been a benefit for my secure data as it requires the knowledge of the key holder to allow others the information. This is `A` to `B`, which is possible but `B` has to have edit access to `A`'s spreadsheet.

No, `B` cannot get information from `A` unless they have access to it, as least as viewer.  You cannot grant viewing privileges to individual cells, which is essentially what you want to do.

Without that ability, the solution is more in structuring the flow of the data.  In one senerio where a user proved they can't be trusted to update the team regularly, I've create myself as `0`.  I have permissions to `A` and `B`.  I run the function from `0` to access `A` and to update `B`, which also sends them an email, so all know when the last update has happened.  Why don't I just use `A` spreadsheet to run the function, because from `0` I can access it and write it to `B`  without ever seeing the data. It's a veil of ignorance.  I never actually open `A` and `0` remains empty.

Best I could do.

Comment: a normal onEdit Trigger can't access services that require authentication, but an installable onEdit Trigger can. Furthermore installable Triggers "run as the user who installed the trigger, not as the user triggering the event." Therefore it is also possible to access data for which the user of the spreadsheet would normally not have permissions. The dead end is that I have found no way to trigger an installable trigger via a button or a menuentry
The workaround with a masteruser starting the script to get the data from A to B doesn't work for my case as the data has to be updated too often

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar  problem.

I think that i found a workaround but no guarantee.
I used the `importrange` function which i intend to control via script.
I have tried the flush function and found it is a good trigger to force the `importrange` to work, which I added to a `Menu` (just in case).

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [];
    menuEntries.push({name: "Refresh", functionName: "SheetFlush"});
    ss.addMenu("Menu", menuEntries);
}

function SheetFlush() {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Now, as i don't want the `B` user to know the `A` SS unique address.
(when looking to the `importrange` function)

I am protecting and hiding the sheet with the `importrange` function in the `B` SS. And Im using an extra internal refernce in `B` SS for the hidden sheet.

Comment: but as much as I understood the ImportRange function [(see Note)](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=fr&answer=155183) the user still needs to have access to ss B to be able to get the data from B...

Comment: For now, I have checked it on a demo, and you don't need to share an importrange document. (see my note : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearch/author:me/docs/03LgWZbRPUE).

Comment: hmm, maybe i am making something different but i get a #REF Error if the document is not shared. I found another way publishing my service as a webservice but with that solution (without using google apps) it seems that i have no possibility to control who can access the script...

Answer (score 0):

I might have an answer for your anomaly.
My application client are people from my googleapp workgroup, they don't have permission
to view the files, but they are not a complete strangers.

I think that the following might work.
A file is the muster file with the code.
B file has importrange() function from A with a sharing permission.
And C file has importrange() from B with a sharing permmsion of B file.
the small twist is that B file has a linked sheet which is hide and protected.
I have check this, and if you are not the owner you will be able to unhide it.

In practice, my filling is that you can pull a similar trick with 2 SpreadSheets, 
the third one is for extra safety.

Comment: that might explain it, unluckily we are not having a google apps account that makes everything a lot more complicated, if you have a google apps account you might also give the server class in scriptapp class a look because you can do the same staff without importrange with it, thx for your efforts